# Border-style not working on a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div, with the style shown below, and I would like a nice border around it.
The border-radius works, but the border-style and border-width does not show. I can't see why this is happening.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.request{
   background-color: #CDCDCD;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:block;
   width:700px;
   height:2000px;
   text-align:center;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #000000
   border-style: outset;
   border-width:5px;
   border-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius:25px;
   padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='request'>
      <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est                 laborum."
      </p>
      <p>

      </p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a `;` near `box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #000000`. Every CSS-Rule -*expect the last one*- must have the closing semicolon. To prevent errors you should always add the `;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rnx7m/

```
/** This is always working */
div.request{
  margin: 25px;
  padding:10px /* missing semicolon ignored by browsers */
}

/** This is an error */
div.request{
  margin: 25px /* Breaking */
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you... Please mark the answer as accepted if you have no further questions.

Answer (score 1):

the closing `;` is missing at the end of the following line: `box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #000000`